# Angular 13 with Boostrap 5 Carousel not working on build version

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-5, angular13

I am trying to use Bootstrap 5 Carousel slide in my Angular 13 project. Everything works fine in development with `ng serve`, but once I build a production version `ng build` it's not working, the carousel is missing slide effect, next image appears immediately under the sliding away image. Am I missing something in setup?

Repo: https://github.com/ebem/angular-bs-carousel

I added .js and .css file in angular.json

```
  "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
  "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

And added carousel (example from bootstrap) in app.component.html

```html
<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/311/200/300.jpg?hmac=ltcRErkHQZRTlJl3xZ_6HSzWzco1GSU3zbZhA12WvJw" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1057/200/300.jpg?hmac=NbjAWVAsLFsIna7Sw8vp4X2BhTpao1KbwORuUZlAcWw" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/718/200/300.jpg?hmac=33vt_lg60EIOuc--jquKwN9epg7jFtlsroU-yn2NvLw" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll be better off using a dedicated bootstrap library for angular. For example [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap), [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) or [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) which is still somewhat in development. It allows tree-shaking and will work as expected.

Comment: If I add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
` in index.html then it works.. so it's something with JS.

Comment: I make a little example in [this stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g4bxyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and looks like work. (your github has no "buttons" nor css, so I don't know want can happens with your code)